# in QGIS, how do I map "most recent date"

Tags: qgis, shapefile, merge, overlapping-features

I have a series of shapefiles indicate locations of controlled burns in an area, which are named using the date of the burn. Many locations have been burned multiple times over the years, so there is considerable overlap of shapefiles.

I want to create a map that shows the date of the most recent burn, with no overlap. I basically want to stack them with the most recent on top, then erase any overlapping areas.
I'm sure this is a very easy procedure for an experienced QGIS user, but I'm very new at this and I've spent an embarrassing amount of time trying to figure this out.

Comment: Try someting like: 1. Polygons to lines, 2. Split with lines, 3. Delete duplicates, 4. Join attributes by location

Comment: What do you mean by show it "with no overlap"? Do you want to show the full shape of the most recent event only, or do you want to show where this most recent event has no overlap with past events? The first you can do with rule-based styling and a rule like `BURNDATE = maximum(BURNDATE)` - the second requires some processing.