# Aggregate using one field and retain corresponding attribute from another field in QGIS

Tags: qgis, overlapping-features, qgis-modeler, aggregation

This is a follow up question to my previous question [Clip polygons to retain only top polygon in areas of overlap using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/445326) and its [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/445326/clip-polygons-to-retain-only-top-polygon-in-areas-of-overlap-using-qgis/445336#445336).

I have successfully aggregated my overlapping polygons to retain the most recent fire age (maximum year), but I also want to record the fire type (one of two possible choices) for each section of polygon that is retained. I can't work out how to do this within Aggregate because fire type will be an attribute of whichever section of polygon has the maximum year for a particular area.

Is there another function that could help here?

I am working in QGIS 3.16.14.

Comment: Just add the field in the aggregate with function first_value, or last value. You might need to sort the Union first

Comment: Thanks. I did experiment with first_value before, but didn't think about the sorting. FYI to others, I used Order by expression with Year_num || Fire_type to first sort by year and then fire type within year (descending).